# Font Awesome icons not being shown

Tags: css, webpack, font-awesome, yarnpkg, symfony-3.3

I'm struggling with webpack to manage my assets right now.
I've installed font-awesome with yarn, and imported the .css files in my web page.
My problem is that, even though my html recognises the classes from font-awesome.css, the icons im trying to use are shown ass squares filled with four numbers (which identify the icon)

My webpack code is:

```
// webpack.config.js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const HandlebarsPrecompiler = require('webpack-handlebars-precompiler');

Encore
// the project directory where all compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('web/build/')
    // .addEntry('fs', 'empty')
// the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
.setPublicPath('/build')

.addEntry('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf', './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')
.addEntry('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot', './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')
.addEntry('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg', './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg')
.addEntry('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')
.addEntry('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2', './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2')

.addEntry('fonts/font-awesome', './node_modules/components-font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css')
.addEntry('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot', './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot')
.addEntry('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg', './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg')
.addEntry('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf', './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf')
.addEntry('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff', './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff')
.addEntry('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2', './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2')

.addEntry('css/bootstrap', './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
.addEntry('css/bootstrap-theme', './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css')
.addEntry('css/bootstrap-datepicker', './node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')

.addEntry('css/app', './src/SgbBundle/Resources/public/css/app.css')

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

The thing is that in the inspector, when I see the rules being used in some html content like

```
<i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-4x" aria-hidden="true" id="icon"></i>
```

recognises the `'fa'` class, the `'fa-4x'` class but no the `'fa-graduation-cap'` class. And the icon is shown as an empty square.
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried "fas fa-graduation-cap fa-4x", adding an extra 's'

Comment: Do you tried with the online link version?

Comment: Yes, the online version didn't work.

Comment: what version, V4  or V5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.
I've installed two versions of font-awesome via Yarn add.
One is components-font-awesome and the other one just font-awesome.
If you check on my webpack configuration, Im adding files from this two dependencies.

```
.addEntry('fonts/font-awesome', './node_modules/components-font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css')
.addEntry('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot', './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot')
```

I solved my issue by just using font-awesome

```
.addEntry('fonts/font-awesome', './node_modules/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css')
.addEntry('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot', './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot')
```

And deleting 'components-font-awesome'.
To sum up, I was trying to use files from two same but different packages.

Answer (score 1):

`fa-graduation-cap` is a new icon class in Font Awesome `5.0.0`. The equivalent icon class in version 4 was `fa-mortar-board`.

So you'd need to make sure that you're loading Font Awesome 5 and not 4 if you want to use that v4 name. It's not evident from your code listing above which version of Font Awesome you're loading.

You can find a reference on upgrading from version 4 to version 5, including the full list of icon classes that changed from v4 to v5 [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4).

Or if you're stuck in Font Awesome 4 and you need a version 4 reference to lookup icon names and codes, make sure you use [the older one here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/). A link to that is found in the footer links on `fontawesome.com`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding it from CDN, The link is below
`https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`

There is No error in  tag